# How do you minimize a positive semidefinite matrix with trace constraint?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, trace, positive-semidefinite, non-convex-optimization

Let $X$ be the matrix that you need to optimize. The problem is
$$\min \qquad \frac{1}{a^T X a}$$
$$\text{subject to} \qquad trace(X) = 1$$
$$\qquad   X \succeq 0$$

Here $a \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$. In my opinion, since it is like in the form of $\frac{1}{x}$ (and hence non convex?) in the positive plane for 1 dimensional case, the optimal value should be as big x as possible (1 in the case of 1 dimension).

Comment: The set of PSD matrices is convex. I did not get the point that "a non-convex positive semidefinite matrix."

Comment: Sorry I meant the problem is non convex since X is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Shit. Made another mistake. a is vector of positive reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\min \qquad \frac{1}{a^{\top} X a}$$
$$\text{subject to} \qquad \mathrm{trace}(X) = 1$$
$$\qquad \ \ \ \ \  X \succeq 0$$
The optimization problem can also be posed as follows,
$$-\min \qquad \mathrm{trace}(XA)$$
$$\text{subject to} \qquad \mathrm{trace}(X) = 1$$
$$\qquad \quad  X \succeq 0$$
where $A=-aa^{\top}$.
This is an SDP. If I am not wrong then this is the SDP relaxation of the MAX-CUT problem.